# How dose soundcloud features divided in django apps

Tags: django

I have read a lot about the rule in django that an app should be focused, an app should do one thing and do it well

so if we are talking about 3 main features in a website like sound cloud

Album: which have many songs

Song: only one song , it could be part of an album

Play list: has an album or some songs

how it would be divided into apps in django

should each one have it's own app with it's own models file and use each app in the other as the have relations

Comment: I can't see any reason to use more than a single app for this use case. But that's just an opinion. This kind of question is off topic for Stack Overflow, since there's no correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put all this under the same app.

It is recommended to build a new app when you change focus. For instance, if you decide that you are going to provide videos or pictures. 
But in this case, the playlist, albums or single is just a mean of display. The logic behind is always the same.

Cheers,
Julien